# How to use Next JS to send POST requests to Salesforce Marketing Cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, api

#### The problem

I'm building a site on Next.JS to collect emails and I need to send the emails to a Salesforce Marketing Cloud data extension via the API.

I first need to request an SFMC token then send the email to the data extension in two separate API calls.

I have the API working fine on Postman but am at a loss as to how to get it working on Next.JS.

I can't just put the standard Post request into a component as it gives me a CORS error, so i move it inside the API routes folder at `/api/emails` so it now becomes

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
 
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": {{et_client_id}},
  "client_secret": {{et_client_secret}},
  "account_id": {{et_account_Id}}
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

const response = await fetch("https://{{et_subdomain}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", requestOptions)
const data = await response.json()
console.log(data)
}
```

I then call the API inside the component when the submit button is clicked

```
  async function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("/api/emails", **UNSURE WHAT TO PUT HERE**);
    console.log(response);
  }
```

I'm not getting any response at all, i've tried a bunch of variations from what i've found here and on Google but can't find any solid resources for calling external APIs that seem to work.

The second API call to send the email is

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify([
  {
    "keys": {
      "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    "values": {
      "date_collected": "2018-05-23T14:32:00Z",
      "source": "API Test",
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company": null
    }
  }
]);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/hub/v1/dataeventsasync/key:{DE_External_Key}/rowset", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I know how to add the collected email into it but am not sure how to structure this on Next to send to Salesforce.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log(data)` statement in your API route simply prints to `stdout` — it won't actually send a response. To do that, the `res` object has several [helper methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers) available, such as `res.json()`:

```js
const response = await fetch("https://{{et_subdomain}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", requestOptions);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data); // prints to `stdout`
res.json(data);    // sends the actual response
```

Then in your component, use the `json()` method of the `Response` interface to access the data. You're currently printing the `Response` object itself; you'll want the parsed response body instead.

```js
async function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch("/api/emails" /*, { method: "POST", ... } */);
  const data = await response.json(); // resolves to a JavaScript object
  console.log(data);                  // use `data` instead of `response`
}
```